# Trying to add KeyboardInterrupt signal_handler but return :

Tags: python

I'm trying to add a KeyboarInterrupt signal in my code so I search on google something to help, And I found this :

```
import signal
import sys

def sigint_handler(signal, frame):
    print 'Interrupted'
    sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sigint_handler)
```

When I try it on Python IDLE I got that:

```
>>> import signal
>>> import sys
>>> def sigint_handler(signal, frame):
...     print('interrupted')
...     sys.exit(0)
... signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't really know what I need to do..

I learn by myself (Python and English lol) So I am not very experienced. Any help is welcome

Comment: When you are typing in code directly at an interactive Python prompt, you have to end multi-line statements (such as your `def`) with a blank line.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll don't forget it anymore.